Can Pyspark HASH() safely convert UUID/GUID to BIGINT maintaining uniqueness in Databricks?
Background
I am working on a Databricks Lakehouse implementation and we are creating some surrogate keys for several tables to facilitate standardizing downstream joins. We have data coming from a number of different systems that use different kinds of identifier key and we are standardizing them to use one surrogate key.
We started with using expr("uuid()") to generate UUIDs as our keys. However, on further research it seems like we could achieve better storage efficiency and query performance if we could use a BIGINT (LongType()) surrogate key instead.
Size of tables: In the reference primary table where the keys are generated we're looking at 200-300k rows. And in the downstream referring tables that have a foreign key reference we have tables in the billions and multi-trillion row range.
Alternatives we tried
Spent some time investigating whether Delta Lake's new(ish) IDENTITY column would satisfy this requirement. It does provide BIGINT key generation, but it has a major limitation in that if a table is defined with an IDENTITY column, it cannot receive concurrent writes from multiple incoming sources. That was a chief limitation cited in this discussion of this feature in this video.
Potential Solution?
Looking at wrapping the uuid() call in a xxHash64() function to hash the UUID into a BIGINT. Looking at the list of standard pyspark.sql hash functions this one seemed like the one that could ensure we have a BIGINT (though given our row sizes, perhaps just a 32-bit hash() might work as well?)
Questions

Is doing withColumn('id', F.xxHash64(F.expr("uuid()"))) a good idea? It seems like it will meet the requirement, but not sure if there are any hidden gotchas in this approach either in performance or potential duplicates.
Is it a valid to assume that if the uuid() function guarantees uniqueness, hashing it will also result in unique values?
Would we need to use 64-bit hash or would a 32-bit hash be sufficient (at row counts fewer than 1M)?


UUIDs are 128bit length (stored as strings of 36 characters it's ), Long's are (irrespective of hash or not) only 64bit.  You will get collisions.  You can convert, although not easily / efficiently in native spark (long_pair_from_uuid provides that functionality but there is no python wrapper at time of writing), the uuid string into two longs as store them.
Quality's unique_id allows concurrent writes by combining snowflake id approaches with the spark partition without the overhead of an rng. (mac addresses on the driver node's nic must be unique on a network for a "global" id).  At time of writing there isn't a supported python wrapper though.
There are other benefits for this approach like lookup, it's significantly faster to search for two longs (and an Int with Quality's ids) than strings as well as storage.  The main drawback is integrating things like power bi lookups can become inefficient as linking 64bit longs doesn't work so you have to fall back to strings (which lead Quality to add optimizers to convert strings to the underlying ids for lookup).
There is a bigger issue in using uuids (spark or Quality) you need to be aware of in that they are non-deterministic, if you are just using them before writing out it's fine, but if you are using them to make joins (not using the results written to disk) then you can get very surpising behaviour.

Thank you for the reply! Another colleague of mine pointed out the 128-bit vs 64-bit mismatch. Based on discussion internally we are leaning toward just sticking with the UUID rather than doing a bunch of convoluted steps to get an integer.
We are only generating UUIDs at write-time. From there everything downstream is just using what is already stored.

yeah if you can deal with the perf impact it's not worth the extra hassle.
